# c# Is there any reason to compare String.contains to true inside if?

Tags: c#, .net

I met with this code:

```
if(message.Contains("some text") == true)
```

what makes me suspicious what was intention of author. Contains() always returns bool, so cleaner version should be:

```
if(message.Contains("some text"))
```

Am I right or there is any scenario when previous solution has pros?

Comment: There's a larval stage whilst learning to program where *every* `if` "**has**" to contain a comparison operator. Most people grow out of it quite quickly. How experienced was the author of this code?

Comment: I prefer the latter, it's easier to read.

Comment: There is, however, another opinion that by explicitly putting the `== true` you make it very clear that the intent is that this should be `true`. The opposite is a better example `!message.Contains("some text")` is not as as clear as `message.Contains("some text") == false`.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any scenario where it makes sense to use `if(condition == true)` instead of just `if(condition)`?

Yes, if you use the null-conditional operator which returns a nullable type:

```
string message = null;
if(message?.Contains("some text") == true)
{
   // ...
}
```

without `==` this would not compile because a `Nullable<bool>` is not a `bool`.

Another reason might be that you prefer `somelongcondition == false` over `!somelongcondition` because it's easy to overlook the exclamation mark.

In the following case i would prefer to choose a more meaningful name, but if that's not possible `== true` or `== false` at least shows that it's a bool:

```
if (flag123 == true)
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is exactly the same. In fact, the compiler will optimize these types of calls to remove the superfluous comparison so:

```
if(message.Contains("some text") == true)
```

will actually be compiled as:

```
if(message.Contains("some text"))
```

So long as the method returns `bool` (and not `bool?`, which would actually be a compile time error)